# Beginner Programmer c++(local vs global variable declaration)

Tags: c++, global-variables, local-variables

I'm new to programming. I was trying to get the sum of the equation added to the previous value when I noticed some strange behavior.

If I declare `int result` inside `int main ()` then I get a blank answer, but if I declare `int result` outside `int main ()` then I get these values: 6,11,16...91,96,101. It doesn't make sense to me since I have no other function.

Why does this happen?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int y =1;
  int result;

  while (result <100)
  {
     result = y +5;
     cout << result << ",";
     y = result;

  }
}
```

Comment: [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b339bef1faf5e3ac) isn't quite as forgiving.

Comment: Why do you need two variables? You can just do `y = y + 5;`

Answer (score 5):

Within a function, `int result;` declares a variable named `result`, but doesn't initialize it to any particular value.  Until you assign it a value it could be anything, and the behavior when reading from it is undefined.  Thus when you read its value in your `while` condition it could be anything; your loop may execute or it may not.  You need to supply an initial value for `result` to make the behavior of your program well-defined:

```
int result = 0;
```

Unlike local variable, global variables are defined to be initialized to a default value when no initial value is explicitly provided, so when you read the value of `result` in your `while` condition, it is `0`, and your loop executes.